# Pattern matching inside awk

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I intend to modify the output of ls -la to display the output of `file` command.
The below command works well for the purpose

```
find /opt -type f | xargs ls -let | awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" } { sprintf("file \"%s\"", $10) | getline type; print type,$1,$3,$4 }' | tr ":" "\t"
```

Now, I want to modify this to display the ouput of `ldd` command(comma separated), if the file type output matches pattern "ELF.*execuatble". I tried various combinations to match a keyword using `if` inside that awk, and if the match is successful, to run `ldd`, but to no avail.

Is this possible?

The operating system is Solaris and I am working in ksh.

Comment: I failed to run your awk code on solaris. what do you intend with `sprintf("file \"%s\"", $10) | getline type` ? shouldn't you use `printf "file \%s\" %s %s %s\n",$10,$1,$3,$4 ; ` ? have you consider changing your find clause to `find bin -type f -ls -exec file {} \;` ?

Comment: @Archemar I intended to print the output of file command on the files. Your version works too with minor modifications I am sure.
I did not consider the command you just gave - guess i should have. It prints out the exact same thing but in two lines which I will try to work around. Seems like I was unnecessarily complicating my life with the basic requirement.
Thanks much!

To run on solaris, use `/usr/xpg4/bin/` binaries in PATH - am able to run my command using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk provides pattern matching

```
awk '/ELF*.executable/ { ... }'
```

EDIT: in your case:

```
find /opt -type f | xargs ls -let | awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t" } /ELF*.executable/ { sprintf("file \"%s\"", $10) | getline type; print type,$1,$3,$4 }' | tr ":" "\t"
```

Comment: I already am using an awk and running a command within, and i was looking at pattern matching the output of that command. Don't think that is doable because awk within awk won't be an option.

Comment: Not inside, just add the pattern to your awk command. I added my answer. Btw: why you use ls -le, in my understanding -l and -e is the same, except the timestamp, so -e would be enough.